# udev rule order and link_priority

Tags: linux, udev

How does the `link_priority` option in udev rules relate to the orders in which rules are processed? For example, take this snippet from the default udev rules:

```
50-udev-default.rules:

# select "system RTC" or just use the first one
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", ATTR{hctosys}=="1", SYMLINK+="rtc"
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", KERNEL=="rtc0", SYMLINK+="rtc", OPTIONS+="link_priority=-100"
```

This will create a /dev/rtc symlink to the RTC device which has the `hctosys` attribute set, i.e. the one that provided the system time. Or, if no RTC device provided the system time, this will just pick the `/dev/rtc0`.

Now let's assume we reverse the order. We could even split them in separate files:

```
10-custom.rules:
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", KERNEL=="rtc0", SYMLINK+="rtc", OPTIONS+="link_priority=-100"

[...]

50-udev-default.rules:
SUBSYSTEM=="rtc", ATTR{hctosys}=="1", SYMLINK+="rtc"
```

Would this be equivalent to the first version? Or will this result in a first symlink being created to `/dev/rtc0`, which would then be overwritten with a second symlink to whatever RTC device provided the system time (assuming it was a different one than rtc0, that is) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reversing the order will be equivalent, independent whether reversed in the original `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` or in a separate `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-custom.rules` file.

What defines the symlink in this case is the `link_priority` value. The default `link_priority` is `0`, so as long there is an rtc providing `hctosys` it will always be higher than the `rtc0`'s `link_priority=-100`.

Note that changing the rule to a higher `link_priority` in a custom `10-custom.rules` file won't work as it will be overridden by the original `50-udev-default.rules` file as it has a higher file number. So use a number > 50 in your custom rule filename.

Comment: What do you mean with overriden? Won't both rules be processed regardless of whether they are in the same file or in separate files?

Comment: If in the file `10-custom-rules` you set a `link-priority` of `100` and it is defined at `-100` in `50-udev-default.rules`, the `-100` will be the final value as for equal rules the higher file name will be the one that sets the value.